# Dojo loader not loading widget's dependencies used in callbacks?

Tags: javascript, dojo, js-amd

I am having a real problem with Dojo's loader. I find it really hard to paste code here, as it's a problem that involves the application as a whole.
I created a widget called `LoginForm` which starts like this:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"app/globals",
"app/stores",
"dijit/form/Form",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"dijit/layout/TabContainer",
"dijit/layout/StackContainer",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/form/Button",
"app/widgets/ValidationPassword",
"app/widgets/ValidationEmail",
"app/widgets/AlertBar",
"app/widgets/StackFading",
"app/widgets/TabFading",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"app/widgets/BusyButton",
"dojo/_base/json",
"dojo/_base/fx",
"dojo/text!app/widgets/templates/LoginForm.html",

], function(
  declare,
 ...
 , json
 , baseFx
 , templateString
 ){
// Create the "login" pane, based on a normal ContentPane
return declare('app.LoginForm', [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {

  widgetsInTemplate: true,

  templateString:  templateString,
```

This is a simple widget using a template and, within the template, some sub-widgets as explained here.

Now... I am trying to create an object of Loginform type in an Ajax callback.
However, the loader is failing me.

The MAIN screen of the app reads like this:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"app/widgets/Dashboard",
"app/globals",
"dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/layout/StackContainer",
"dijit/layout/TabContainer",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane",
"app/widgets/SearchPage",

 ], function(
 declare
 , _WidgetBase
...
 , SearchPage


){
// Create the "login" pane, based on a normal ContentPane
return declare('AppMainScreen', [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {
```

...

That third widget, Dashboard, has just a button:

```
define([
"dojo/_base/declare",
"app/globals",
"app/defaultSubmit",
"app/stores",
"dijit/form/Form",
"dijit/_WidgetBase",
"dijit/_TemplatedMixin",
"dijit/_WidgetsInTemplateMixin",
"app/widgets/AlertBar",
"app/widgets/BusyButton",
"dojo/_base/json",
"dojo/domReady!",

], function(
  declare
 , g
 , ds
 , stores
 , Form
 , _WidgetBase
 , _TemplatedMixin
 , _WidgetsInTemplateMixin
 , AlertBar
 , BusyButton
 , json
){
// Create the "login" pane, based on a normal ContentPane
return declare('app.Dashboard', [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin, _WidgetsInTemplateMixin ], {


widgetsInTemplate: true,

templateString: '' +
    '<div>' +
    '  <div data-dojo-type="app.AlertBar" data-dojo-attach-point="alertBar"></div>' +
    '  <form data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Form" data-dojo-attach-point="form" method="POST"> ' +
    '    <input type="submit" data-dojo-attach-point="button" data-dojo-type="app.BusyButton" label="Create!" />' +
    '  </form>' +
    '</div>',
```

The onSubmit for that form is then linked to a function in `"app/defaultSubmit",` which reads:

```
define([
'app/globals',
'dijit/registry',
'dojo/query',
'dojo/aspect',
'dojo/_base/lang',  
'dojo/_base/json',
'dijit/Tooltip',
'dijit/Dialog',
'app/widgets/LoginForm',
],function(
g
, registry
, query
, aspect
, lang
, json
, Tooltip
, Dialog
, LoginForm
){
```

The problem is that LoginForm doesn't work, because LoginForm's constructor doesn't work: it says it cannot instantiate one of the dependent classes.

NOW, if I add this to the app's mainScreen's postCreate:

```
var loginForm = new LoginForm({});
```

Then, within the callback, LoginForm() magically works (!).

I know that I didn't post all of the code, but is there any magic I need to know about, in terms of how dependencies are handled in AMD? How can I make sure that a module is resolved within a callback...?

Bye,

Merc.

Comment: Is the `LoginForm` used declaratively in a template anywhere? (It must be loaded before this template is parsed.)

Comment: It's used declaratively on another page (the login page!). I was planning on using it programmatically in the callback when the session expires and the user needs to login again (I create it in a dialog). What do you mean by "It must be loaded before this template is parsed"? I am so lost... How does the loading mechanism actually work? How could come of the variables in the declare's function's callback be empty/undefined, if they are set as dependencies for the module...?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*These remarks won't really fit in the comments section.*

I can't see the defect in your code, but here are some things to look at.

**Notes on the AMD loader**

Don't make assumptions about load order.

```
require(["foo", "bar", function (foo, bar) {
  // use foo and bar
});
```

Either `foo` or `bar` might be loaded and invoked first as loading is asynchronous. The only thing that is guaranteed is that they will both be loaded when the callback function is invoked. The thing `"foo"` resolves to is whatever its `define` function returns; if this is `undefined` ensure function is returning a value.

Avoid circular dependencies.

```
//bar.js
define(["foo"], function (foo) {
  return {};
});

//foo.js
define(["bar"], function (bar) {
  return {};
});
```

The behaviour is defined (see [documentation on modules](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/modules/)) but can be difficult to manage. Check that you don't introduce these through transitive dependencies (`A` -> `B` -> `C` -> `A`.)

Load transitive template dependencies before trying to [parse](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/parser.html) templates.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare", "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/form/Button" //need to load this even though it is
                            //not referenced in the function
       ],
        function(declare, _WidgetBase, parser) {

    // pretend this is some custom template format (e.g. DTL)
    var template = "<div data-dojo-type='dijit.form.Button'></div>";

    return declare("foo.Foo", [_WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin], {
        postCreate: function() {
            this.domNode.innerHTML = template;
            parser.parse(this.domNode);
        }
    });

});
```

Use the `_WidgetsInTemplateMixin` with [standard template widgets](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/templated/) where appropriate.

Also, be sure to read the [1.7 release notes](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/releasenotes/1.7.html) for gotchas and caveats.

*Note: this code is untested.*

---

*As an aside, a trailing comma on an array will cause an error in IE7.*

Comment: Thank you!!! In the end, I had the perfect storm of circular dependencies and that damn "app" as a global variable... thanks for your help. I did a _major_ refactoring of the code in the meantime... "I guess" it was a good thing. Sort of. THANKS!

Comment: As an aside, people using Explorer 7 can go and use other software, as I won't even consider them. :D